# foreach dentro do foreach sem repetir os dados

Tags: php, html, sql

Tenho uma listagem de Funcionários e cada funcionário pode ter muitos Centros de Custo.

E quanto trago a informação do funcionário do banco preciso listar os centros de custos e listar os centros de custo em que o funcionário está cadastrado marcando o select como selected.

```
$intCentroCustoId = $this->modelo->arrComboCentroCustoFuncionario; // traz o array da listagem de centros de custo que o funcionario está cadastrado
    $arrComboBar = $this->modelo->arrComboBar; // traz todos os centros de custos
    /*echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($intCentroCustoId);
    echo '</pre>';*/

    echo "<select data-minlength-error='Selecione pelo menos um'
                                                data-placeholder='Digite ou selecione' data-minlength='1'
                                                multiple='multiple' name='arrCentroCusto[]'
                                                id='arrCentroCusto'
                                                class=\"js-basic-multiple form-control\" required>"; // monta a select multiplo
    if(isset($arrComboBar) && !empty($arrComboBar)){ // verifica se a combo não esta vazia
        echo "<option></option>";//primeiro option vazio
        foreach($arrComboBar as $arrLinha){ //listagem completa dos centros de custos
            foreach ($intCentroCustoId as $CC)
                    if($CC['id_centro_custo'] == $arrLinha['idcusto']){
                        echo "<option value='".$CC['id_centro_custo']."' selected>";
                        echo utf8_decode($arrLinha['departamento']);
                        echo "</option>";
                    }

                    else{
                        echo "<option value='".$arrLinha['idcusto']."'>";
                        echo utf8_decode($arrLinha['departamento']);
                        echo "</option>";
                    }


        }

    }
    echo "</select>";
```

Meu problema é que a listagem fica repetida, dependendo de quantos centros de custo o funcionário está cadastrado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para listar todos os centro de custos com os 3 selecionados e sem repetir?

Comment: Olá Jonathan tudo bom? esses dados tu está trazendo de um banco de dados é isso? 
no select que traz os dados do banco de dados tu está usando o ' SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table_name; ' por dai tu não terá nenhum dado repetindo vindo do banco.
Mas caso eu estiver errado, talvez não entendi bem sua pergunta.

Comment: Minha pergunta é, como não repetir os valores que estão no Select Option. São 3 tabelas, a que lista os funcionários, a que lista os centros_custo e a que lista centro_custo_funcionarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, o problema é que seu echo do option está dentro dos 2 `foreachs`, então ele vai repetir, eu tirei o echo de dentro de um dos `foreach` e dei uma resumida no seu código:

```
if(isset($arrComboBar) && !empty($arrComboBar)){ // verifica se a combo não esta vazia

    echo "<option></option>";//primeiro option vazio

    foreach($arrComboBar as $arrLinha){ //listagem completa dos centros de custos
      foreach ($intCentroCustoId as $CC){

        if($CC['id_centro_custo'] == $arrLinha['idcusto']){
          $selected = ' selected';
          break;
        }else{
          $selected = '';
        }

      }

      echo "<option value='".$arrLinha['idcusto']."'".$selected.">";
      echo utf8_decode($arrLinha['departamento']);
      echo "</option>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, era isso que precisava